# how to get gnome environment while working in gnome

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

just some moments ago I installed kubuntu environment and switched to kubuntu but when i return to my GNOME desktop environmentI cannot get the pure desktop and many applications appear as if they are running on kubuntued GNOME

I want to get complete GNOME environment while I use it can I get it ?

here down is a screenshot of mozilla which also appears as that of kubuntu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install desktop Environment (gnome)

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

$ sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
```

restart & log in 
or

you can also install the gnome 3 (fedora luncher)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

When prompted, select the login manager of choice (LightDM is the default Unity manager and GDM is the GNOME default -- either will work).
When the installation completes, close the terminal and reboot the system.
Select GNOME at the login screen and log in.